# Где можно скачать видеокурсы по JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Где можно скачать видеокурсы по JavaScript?

Comment: Есть видеокурсы по javascript и jquery, если нужно, могу залить куда-нибудь на обменник, только вечером, ибо сейчас на работе.

Comment: Мне нужен именно Javascript веб, потому что я начинающий верстальщик (ну пропустим формальности).

Comment: Сдается, что человеку именно ява нужна, а не скрипты.

Comment: javascript  если вам не трудно будьте добры залейте на Dump.ru

Comment: ОК, вечером залью, только на dump.ru размер не больше 320Мб, а курс, если мне не изменяет память весит в районе 2,5Гб, потому придется кучей архивов делать.

Comment: Спасибо,metazet мне и то и другое нужно грубо говоря. Сама ява для модификации 1 вещицы написанной на ява)

Comment: еще нужен курс по JavaScript и Jquery?, могу скинуть ссылку, сам по нему учился)))

Comment: С нетерпением жду!Евгений536 большое спасибо но не нужно!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что "где скачать" не является технической проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот я вам советую видео курс Попова. Если Вы начинающий, то это идеальный вариант. (Плюсик в студию).

Answer (score 0):

Советую посмотреть  вебинары от "Специалиста".