# Самоучители по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Посоветуйте видео уроки по javascript, желательно без консоли.

Comment: покажите мне видеокурс по javascript с консолью.

Буду очень признательным ^.^

Comment: Javascript. Больше чем просто сайт (2010) PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Самоучитель по Javascript и jQuery](http://katushka.net/torrents/other/69540/)

**Единственная поправка!!!**данный торрент только сейчас сам скачал и о качестве сказать ничего не могу, но по содержанию интересно достаточно. Размер файла - 5,29Гб

Answer (score 2):

- [JavaScript с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1842/javascript-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)
- [JavaScript с 0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24923/javascript-%D1%81-0)
- [Где можно скачать видеокурсы по JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28017/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript)
- [Самоучитель по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30197/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript)
- [Задачи на закрепление JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33571/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript)
- [C чего начать изучение JS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44594/c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-js)

Answer (score 0):

### Видео уроки школы специалист:

- JavaScript. Уровень 1. Основы веб-программирования 2009
- JavaScript. Уровень 2. Расширенные возможности 2010

Comment: смотрел когда уже знал основы...
Откровенно говоря не понравилось, навскидку прикинул сколько бы времени у меня ушло если бы я начинал учить js с этих видеоуроков и ужаснулся...

Comment: Ну а когда я начинал, мне они очень понравились.  Да там конечно дается совсем не все. Совсем :) Ну для самого начала вполне. Опять же на мой субъективный взгляд.  Ну а лучше всего, когда есть знания основ, писать свой код и разбирать чужой. Попутно заглядывая в справочники.